# Can I get binned_statistic_2d to return bin numbers for only bins in range?

Tags: python, scipy

Binned_statistic_2d automatically creates bins at the boundaries of each dimension to catch values out of range, making the bin numbers less useful if I am only interested in values within my given range. Is there a way to assign bin numbers to only bins within range?

For example:

```
x = [0.5, 0.5, 1.5]
y = [0.5, 1.5, 1.5]
binx = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
biny = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

ret = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, None, "count", bins = [binx, biny])

ret.statistic
ret.binnumber
```

returns

```
array([[1., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])

array([ 5,  6, 10])
```

because of the "out of bounds bins"

```
  0  |  1  |  2  |  3   
-----+-----+-----+-----
  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  
-----+-----+-----+-----
  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  
-----+-----+-----+-----
 12  | 13  | 14  | 15
```

What can I do to instead return `array([ 0,  1, 3])` and cut to just the bins in interested in?

```
  0  |  1   
-----+-----
  2  |  3
```

I feel like there may be a way to do it using `expand_binnumbers = True` and doing some math with the x and y indices, but maybe there's an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned binnumbers form a `(nx+2)x(ny+2)` grid. The desired restricted binnumbers form a `(nx)x(ny)` grid.

If we draw `x` from left to right, and `y` from bottom to top, we need to subtract:

- two cells for each smaller column (one cell at the top and one at the bottom) (green)
- one complete column of `x`'s (noting that 2 of these cells have been subtracted in the previous step) (orange)
- and, finally, the first cell of the current column (yellow).

This results in the formula (using numpy's broadcasting):

```
ny = len(biny) - 1 # there is one bin less than there are boundaries
restriced_binnumber = ret.binnumber - 2 * (ret.binnumber // (ny+2)) - ny - 1
```

The following overview illustrates the renumbering for `nx=4; ny=3` for the cell with original number `18` (and restricted number `18-6-3-1=8`):

[image: overview]